# Focus Cursor in TextView on selected Row

Tags: ios, swift

i would like to see the focus of my TextView inside a TableViewCell. When the Cell is selected, it looses the Focus Cursor (so you can still write, but there is no Cursor)

So i would like to have this:

[image]

And get this when selected.

[image]

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: 
With:

```
self.tableView.setTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
```

The Focus Color is black in TextField, but is not visible in my TextView.

Comment: I know this definitely is not an answer to your question, but perhaps displaying non-editable information in table view cells and navigating to a controller that has an editable textview with prepopulated text is a better design choice. AFAIK using subclasses of UIScrollView inside subclasses of UIScrollView might lead to buggy behavior, this might just be one of such cases.

Comment: Thank you - I know this could be a possible sultion, but in my case this is not very good for my user interface. But if there are no options i would defintive change this (and create a simple popover with my TextView)